# I've to display a popup window when mouseover on Browser's close button. Mouseover on 'X' button next to resize button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a requirement when mouseover occurs on Browser window's close (X) button, I need to display a popup window with shake effect.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
                $( "#shakeform" ).effect( "shake" );
        });
```

I tried following to display popup window on Mouseover but it is not working.

```
var mouse_position_switch = false;
`$(document.body).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
//              alert("2");
                // Check if mouse is near the top
                if(mouse_position_switch){
                // Show modal
                    $.popupWindow('webpage.html', { height: 300, width: 400 });
                }
            });
            // Event listener to set if mouse is near the top or not
            $(document.body).on('mousemove', function(e) {
//              alert("1");
                if(e.clientY < 10){
                    mouse_position_switch = true;
                }else{
                    mouse_position_switch = false;
                } 
            });`
```

Comment: You cant. Mouse events are only available for the client-area of the browser. The close-button exists in the non-client area.